# Matrices and differentiation commute

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Suppose for simplicity we have a plane curve $\gamma(t)=(f(t),g(t))$. I'm just curious exactly what is the property responsible for the fact that, if $R_{90}$ is the two dimensional rotation matrix by $90$ degrees counterclockwise, then $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(R_{90}\left(\gamma(t)\right)\right)=R_{90}\left(\frac{d}{dt}(\gamma(t))\right).$$

I'm thinking this only applies to matrices $R$ that are linear isomorphisms (and for when the multiplication makes sense). What is the general property at work here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can think of this as the chain rule. Qualitatively, the derivative of a linear transformation $T$ at an arbitrary point is $T$ itself. In symbols, $DT(x) = T$ for all $x$ in the domain of $T$.

Comment: Don't we have to require for the chain rule that the linear transformation $T$ is continuous, e. g. by having $dim(Im(T)) < \infty$?

Comment: @user7427029 Technically you're right, we need to assume some notion of differentiability for $T$, an issue if the domain is infinite-dimensional. OP was asking about rotation of a real plane, and in context mentioning differentiability of $T$ seemed ... extraneous. ;)

Answer (score 8):

The main reason is that multiplication by a matrix is a linear operation.
By definition of the differentiability,
$$
\gamma(t) \underset{t\to t_0}{=} \gamma(t_0) + (t-t_0)\gamma'(t_0) + o(t-t_0).
$$
If $M$ is any matrix, the application $u \mapsto M(u)$ is linear and continuous, and thus
$$
M(\gamma(t)) \underset{t\to t_0}{=} M(\gamma(t_0)) + (t-t_0)M(\gamma'(t_0)) + o(t-t_0).
$$
(The continuity is needed to ensure that $M(o(t-t_0)) = o(t-t_0)$.)

Hence, $M\circ\gamma$ is differentiable with $(M\circ\gamma)'=M\circ\gamma'$.

Comment: just to point it out explicitly, this demonstrates that the matrix doesn't have to be an isomorphism (as the questioner guessed it might be).

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$R_{90}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$
so $$R_{90}(\gamma(t))=(-g(t),f(t)).$$

Then as we take derivatives: $$\frac{d}{dt}R_{90}(\gamma(t))=(-g'(t),f'(t))=R_{90}(f'(t),g'(t))=R_{90}\left(\frac{d}{dt}\gamma(t)\right).$$

Of course, Andrew's answer illustrates a more general case.

Comment: Actually, it is $R_{90}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, but the argument is the same

Comment: @Didier Thanks! Corrected.